# How do I do a video glitch with wrap around edges?

Tags: compositing-nodes, video, effects

I want to make a horizontal video glitch that shifts the image across but wraps around on itself. The Translate node can do this to the whole image but won't allow me to do per pixel distortion.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this effect with the Displace node (for distortion) and the Translate node (for wrap around).

Create a texture for the desired skew or offset effect, then send this to the X value of the Displace Node.

[image: Distortion with offset]

Use a Combine RGB node to send a large Value to the Red or Vector X input. The Combine RGB node doesn't allow you to enter a value over 1 unless you type it in. I have added a Value node (the Green node) to make this easier. You animate the amount of distortion with this node.

The Red curve node allows you to modify the nature of the distortion, by modifying the contrast of the texture you can make a pointy effect or a rounded effect.

[image: Distortion pointy with wrap]

In this image you can see that the right edge the image is wrapping around to fill the gap left by the distortion. I have piped the Value node into the x axis of a translate node, then combined it with an Alpha Over onto the distorted offset image.

If I invert the texture then the distortion will affect less of the image.

[image: Invert the amount of distortion]